# First line in URL list must be TsvHttpData-1.0 but it is Google Cloud Transfer Service Error

Tags: service, cloud, transfer

I am trying to import some csv files from Google Cloud to Google Cloud Storage(GCS), but I am getting the error. I can't seem to find what I did wrong. Please help!

URL List - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gDWYfjr2FhSLTHUunQ5cBFmW82PR1vd5/view?usp=sharing

```
Error - First line in URL list must be TsvHttpData-1.0 but it is: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="google" content="notranslate"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;"><style nonce="b0Ey8uWci6arZ81yZ1/Xyw">@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:italic;font-weight:400;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOkCnqEu92Fr1Mu51xIIzc.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc9.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxP.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc9.ttf)format('truetype');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBBc9.ttf)format('truetype');}</style><meta name="referrer" content="origin"><title>URL_List.txt - Google Drive</title><meta property="og:title" content="URL_List.txt"><meta property="og:type" content="article"><meta property="og:site_name" content="Google Docs"><meta property="og:url" content="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gDWYfjr2FhSLTHUunQ5cBFmW82PR1vd5/view?usp=sharing&amp;usp=embed_facebook"><meta property="og:image" content="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/4l6lCAvBKyWxCy42RcB_Y5_1vguKdkscpR8YAUHKTOb4hD8dYH_vrnRxTxMqowI8Zys=w1200-h630-p"><meta property="og:image:width" content="1200"><meta property="og:image:height" content="630"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/drive_2020q4_32dp.png"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Google+Sans:300,400,500,700" nonce="b0Ey8uWci6arZ81yZ1/Xyw"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/_/apps-fileview/_/ss/k=apps-fileview.v.SN2xzHUByys.L.W.O/d=0/rs=AO0039uV2v8KOuxcH9eYr8HNmTKU5aI9VQ" nonce="b0Ey8uWci6arZ81yZ1/Xyw"><script nonce="i7nJhbgQY3EllroO23kuQg">_docs_flag_initialData={"docs-ails":"docs_cold","docs-fwds":"docs_sdf","docs-crs":"docs_crs_nfd","docs-shdn":0,"docs-tfh":"","info_params":{},"docos-eddmh":false,"docs-eohmo":false,"uls":"","docs-obsImUrl":"https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/common/netcheck.gif","docs-api-keys":{},"buildLabel":"texmex_2022.16-Thu_RC00","docs-show_debug_info":false,"ondlburl":"https://docs.google.com","drive_url":"https://drive.google.com","app_url":"https://drive.google.com/file/","docs-itrf":false,"docs-gsmd":"","docs-eidfc":false,"docs-ecpvib":false,"docs-msid":32767,"docs-rid":1024,"docs-mif":1000,"docs-icdmt":[],"docs-mip":6250000,"docs-rawff":2,"docs-mib":5242880,"docs-mid":2048,"docs-sup":"/file","docs-seu":"https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gDWYfjr2FhSLTHUunQ5cBFmW82PR1vd5/edit","docs-crp":"/file/d/1gDWYfjr2FhSLTHUunQ5cBFmW82PR1vd5/view","docs-crq":"usp\u003dsharing","docs-ecvca":true,"docs-uptc":["lsrp","ca","sh","noreplica","ouid","dl","hi","hi_ext","usp","urp","utm_source","utm_medium","utm_campaign","utm_term","utm_content","aaac","sle"],"docs-doddn":"","docs-uddn":"","docs-cwsd":"","docs-epq":false,"docs-erdiiv":false,"docs-acap":["docs.security.access_capabilities",1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"docs-eefufs":false,"docs-eccfs":false,"docs-eefufd":false,"docs-hwg":"DISABLED","docs-hwst":"","docs-ndt":"Untitled Texmex","docs-prn":"","docs-een":false,"docs-as":"","docs-etdimo":false,"docs-mdck":"","docs-etiff":false,"docs-mriim":1800000,"docs-eccbs":false,"docs-rlmp":false,"docs-mmpt":15000,"docs-erd":false,"docs-erfar":false,"docs-ensb":false,"docs-ddts":false,"docs-uootuns":false,"docs-amawso":false,"docs-ofmpp":false,"docs-anlpfdo":false,"docs-eslars":true,"docs-eem":false,"docs-phe":"https://contacts.google.com","docs-wsu":"","docs-wsup":"","docs-pse":"PROD","docs-sccfo":"PROD","docs-eridm":false,"docs-pid":"","docs-eedmlf":false,"docs-emmda":false,"docs-efs":false,"docs-net-edsle":false,"docs-ricocpb":false,"docs-epmdup":false,"docs-rdowr":false,"docs-erep":false,"docs-effnp":false,"docs-cttmtbr":0,"docs-caaffso":true,"docs-eaaswoc":false,"docs-edpsf":true,"docs-edp":false,"docs-edlo":false,"docs-cttmteq":0,"docos-edces":false,"docs-dec":false,"docs-eiasrpu":false,"docs-ectt":false,"docs-ebbouf":false,"docs-ecgd":false,"docs-pcfloc":false,"docs-dsps":false,"docs-embmd":false,"docs-eesce":false,"docs-esmr":false,"docs-eawflb":false,"docs-iosdl":false,"docs-hft":"","docs-ececs":false,"docs-enfa":false,"docs-eerp":false,"docs-ecurf":false,"docs-efsii":false,"docs-plimif":6.0,"docs-elcfd":false,"docs-edmitm":false,"docs-enjec":false,"ecid":true,"docs-eir":false,"docs-eibs":false,"docs-mcciiu":false,"docs-hcwidu":false,"server_time_ms":1651222446455,"gaia_session_id":"","app-bc":"#d1d1d1","enable_iframed_embed_api":true,"docs-fut":"https://drive.google.com#folders/{folderId}","docs-isb":false,"docs-agdc":false,"docs-anddc":true,"docs-adndldc":false,"docs-dhnap":"drive.google.com","docs-ds":"https","docs-text-efnma":false,"docs-text-efrnma":false,"docs-cide":true,"docs-cn":"","docs-depquafr":false,"docs-frbanmc":false,"docs-rldce":false,"docs-dom":false,"docs-ecsup":false,"docs-edamc":false,"docs-edomic":false,"docs-eddm":false,"kix-edrat":false,"kix-edratv2":false,"docs-edhqlfr":false,"docs-eehlb":false,"docs-fwd":false,"docs-efpgwb":false,"docs-efu":false,"docs-eiecr":false,"docs-eiccp":false,"docs-elds":false,"docs-eph":false,"docs-epat":true,"docs-eppd":false,"docs-essph":false,"docs-tdd":false,"docs-rsc":"","docs-rgifem":true,"docs-ssi":false,"docs-uoci":"","docs-wia":"","docs-gth":"","docs-ef":false,"docs-ndsom":[],"docs-dm":"text/plain","docs-sdsom":[],"docs-po":"https://drive.google.com","docs-to":"https://drive.google.com","docs-eastd":true,"opendv":false,"onePickImportDocumentUrl":"","opmbs":5242880,"opmpd":2500,"opbu":"https://docs.google.com/picker","opru":"https://drive.google.com/relay.html","opdu":false,"opccp":false,"ophi":"texmex","opst":"","opuci":"","docs-eopiiv2":true,"projector_base_url":"//drive.google.com","docs-drk":[],"docs-erkpp":false,"docs-erkfsu":true,"jobset":"prod","docs-eqam":false,"docs-ehlib":false,"docs-efcm":false,"docs-euaool":false,"docs-eua":false,"docs-ebfgf":false,"docs-ehib":false,"docs-uahnt":"","docs-esap":false,"docs-efib":false,"docs-eidib":false,"docs-se":false,"docs-eisib":false,"docs-egf":false,"docs-uptuf":true,"docs-eodpb":true,"docs-odpl":false,"docs-surfb":false,"docs-odpdu":[null,null,null,"//drive.google.com/odp/dialog"],"docs-odpu":[null,null,null,"//drive.google.com/odp/embed"],"docs-dafjera":false,"docs-daflia":false,"docs-dafwsa":false,"docs-dafgfma":false,"docs-fta-fnrhci":false,"docs-spdy":true,"xdbcfAllowHostNamePrefix":true,"xdbcfAllowXpc":true,"docs-dbctc":false,"docs-iror":true,"docs-eirj":false,"promo_url":"","promo_second_url":"","promo_title":"","promo_title_prefix":"","promo_content_html":"","promo_more_element_text":"","promo_second_more_element_text":"","promo_element_id":"","promo_orientation":1,"promo_arrow_alignment":0,"promo_show_on_click":false,"promo_hide_arrow":false,"promo_show_on_load":false,"promo_mark_dismissed_on_show":false,"promo_use_material_styling":false,"promo_close_button_text":"","promo_icon_url":"","promo_action_id":"","promo_impression_id":0,"promo_is_contextual":false,"docs-ccwt":80,"docs-epcc":false,"docs-eoodwflb":false,"docs-era":true,"docs-msoil":"docs_spanner","docs-gsoil":"docs_gsabs","docs-fsd":false}; _docs_flag_cek= null ; if (window['DOCS_timing']) {DOCS_timing['ifdld']=new Date().getTime();}</script><script nonce="i7nJhbgQY3EllroO23kuQg">window.viewerData = {config: {'id': '1gDWYfjr2FhSLTHUunQ5cBFmW82PR1vd5', 'title': 'URL_List.txt', 'isItemTrashed': false , 'documentResourceKey': '','enableEmbedDialog': true,'projectorFeedbackId': '99950', 'projectorFeedbackBucket': 'viewer-web',}, configJson: ["",null,null,null,null,1,null,null,null,1,1,[1,null,null,"AIzaSyDVQw45DwoYh632gvsP5vPDqEKvb-Ywnb8",0,null,1,null,null,"AIzaSyC1eQ1xj69IdTMeii5r7brs3R90eck-m7k",null,"/drive/v2beta",0,0,1,[0],null,1,null,0,1,1],null,5,1,null,null,1,"https://drive.google.com",null,null,1,null,1,null,null,null,null,null,1,null,null,[[null,"0"],6,1,1,null,null,null,1],null,1,null,null,[null,null,null,null,"https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service\u003dwise\u0026passive\u003d1209600\u0026continue\u003dhttps://drive.google.com/file/d/1gDWYfjr2FhSLTHUunQ5cBFmW82PR1vd5/view?usp%3Dsharing\u0026hl\u003den\u0026followup\u003dhttps://drive.google.com/file/d/1gDWYfjr2FhSLTHUunQ5cBFmW82PR1vd5/view?usp%3Dsharing",null,null,null,1],null,null,1,null,null,"https://docs.google.com",null,1,[null,0],["https://youtube.googleapis.com",null,2],1,null,null,null,1,null,1,1,null,null,null,null,[1,1,1,1],null,1,null,3,null,null,null,null,1,["AIzaSyCMp6sr4oTC18AWkE2Ii4UBZHTHEpGZWZM","https://blobcomments-pa.clients6.google.com",null,1,1,1,null,null,null,null,"ANONYMOUS_17612595759507348808"],null,1,null,null,0,null,null,1,null,null,null,[1,1,1],null,null,1,1,[null,null,"https://clients6.google.com","AIzaSyD_InbmSFufIEps5UAt2NmB_3LvBH3Sz_8","https://people-pa.googleapis.com",null,null,1,1,1,1],null,1,null,null,null,null,[0,0],null,null,null,null,0,null,0,1,null,null,null,null,null,null,[0,"","","",""],1,[null,null,0,0,0,0,1],null,1,[[null,null,null,"//drive.google.com/odp/embed"],null,"","AIzaSyCIGHYEdm91p31HKyJSoU4at7IqhCViXuA",1,null,[null,null,null,"//drive.google.com/odp/dialog"]],[1],null,null,null,null,1,"https://workspace.google.com",null,null,1,1,1,1,1,null,1,["AIzaSyCMp6sr4oTC18AWkE2Ii4UBZHTHEpGZWZM","https://drivemetadata.clients6.google.com"],0,1,1], itemJson: [null,"URL_List.txt","https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/fj9qJmqhNlMRAfkcUuBs0WZz2fMg5Mvuw9yQu8k75XLETScB2kVe8YEWPFewfF6Xi4kME9XUFwQZoQ\u003dw1600",null,null,null,null,null,null,"https://drive.google.com/viewerng/upload?ds\u003dAPznzaYdfa24fByFIZg3fiKWc8CSgJHZqTiK1CmXJ9rVoufvL2ZVY-c77RFjr0QfWH_8gXZ_3If1-BPOJC2MfrU2lobk9OMLJwckmaAtrFK_dFGEbOL7Xx_tHgs0CqxLbyAMnUfNms9lFfZAIhf9Mn9HJKhpSRjdSqWPjC4WItasfIIKE_5lQKM8lYajOJ8KQVNUvlM4N9Sj1muKZFPvtDJ7tkjNpv7zx5TwpUQj7xYKTFFm-RRal3LfLbGoD28UfBfDYx1aXLI2K6A2eRdBrVZswur9JwDTO8IIwBENy9RYKkdGgZl4wNR2PcriVj45SKOM2g4_gHRmTAYJMDOSwYPP0LpgiBTQX64fAXOhyWqPNLl0gYuVGWE%3D\u0026ck\u003ddrive\u0026p\u003dproj",null,"text/plain",null,null,6,null,"https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gDWYfjr2FhSLTHUunQ5cBFmW82PR1vd5/view",null,"https://drive.google.com/uc?id\u003d1gDWYfjr2FhSLTHUunQ5cBFmW82PR1vd5\u0026export\u003ddownload",null,5,0,null,null,null,[null,null,"101"],null,null,null,null,null,0,"txt",null,[["0B6td48lYowV-WGlDVUtiREtlYjBoNjN5b3pzeVR2U09kbHBJPQ"],[],["1gDWYfjr2FhSLTHUunQ5cBFmW82PR1vd5"]],null,null,null,null,null,null,0,null,0]};</script><script nonce="i7nJhbgQY3EllroO23kuQg">;this.gbar_={CONFIG:[[[0,"www.gstatic.com","og.qtm.en_US.XzJ0ONUNIso.O","com","en","25",0,[4,2,"","","","444135851","0"],null,"rqdrYsWIH5SfqtsPw_KygAo",null,0,"og.qtm.L8VIEKh59Qg.L.X.O","AA2YrTuxcq54HDP2gjPFC5ABnSWGsNBFIw","AA2YrTujoajh5TPNaG7eZGyhbqpOr6S54A","",2,1,200,"USA",null,null,"25","25",1],null,[1,0.1000000014901161,2,1],[1,0.001000000047497451,1],[0,0,0,null,"","","",""],[0,0,"",1,0,0,0,0,0,0,null,0,0,null,0,0,null,null,0,0,0,"","","","","","",null,0,0,0,0,0,null,null,null,"rgba(32,33,36,1)","rgba(255,255,255,1)",0,0,0,null,null,1,0,0],null,null,["1","gci_91f30755d6a6b787dcc2a4062e6e9824.js","googleapis.client:gapi.iframes","","en"],null,null,null,null,["m;/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.Yozr9QYVVr4.O/d=1/rs=AHpOoo8ePFN_mLj5L9BxNRnarRImlQEt0w/m=__features__","https://apis.google.com","","","","",null,1,"es_plusone_gc_20220321.0_p0","en",null,0],[0.009999999776482582,"com","25",[null,"","0",null,1,5184000,null,null,"",null,null,null,null,null,0,null,0,0,1,0,0,0,null,null,0,0,null,0,0,0,0,0],null,null,null,0,null,null,["5061451","google\\.(com|ru|ca|by|kz|com\\.mx|com\\.tr)$",1]],[1,1,null,28834,25,"USA","en","444135851.0",8,0.009999999776482582,0,0,null,null,null,null,"3700949",null,null,null,"rqdrYsWIH5SfqtsPw_KygAo",0,0,0,null,2,5,"rw",6],[[null,null,null,"https://www.gstatic.com/og/_/js/k=og.qtm.en_US.XzJ0ONUNIso.O/rt=j/m=qabr,q_dnp,qapid/exm=qaaw,qadd,qaid,qein,qhaw,qhbr,qhch,qhga,qhid,qhin,qhpr/d=1/ed=1/rs=AA2YrTuxcq54HDP2gjPFC5ABnSWGsNBFIw"]]]],};this.gbar_=this.gbar_||{};(function(_){var window=this;
```

Comment: did you get any workaround cause am stuck at the same level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when you provide the URL to the, it must be to the link which allows you to download the file. You need to modify the URL for this. You can do this as shown below:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=FILE_ID

The FILE_ID is unique for every file in Google Drive. Then you’ll get a direct link to download the file from Google Drive

Answer (score 0):

URL to Tsv file must be publicly available. Looks like transfer service got HTML response with access error rather than the content of the TSV file.